# grammar - Conditionals

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conditional-constructions, grammaticality-in-context

Let's say, I have something that I rarely use, but I don't want to throw it away because I think I may need it ***in the future***. So, do I use *conditional 1 or 2*?

*I thought I should keep it in case I needed to use it.*

or

*I thought I should keep it in case I need to use it.*

Comment: In the past tense the first sentence is correct.  In the present tense you might say, *I think I'll keep it in case I need to use it.* The second sentence would only be correct if it were punctuated: *I thought, "I should keep it in case I need to use it."*

Comment: Both are fine. Idiomatically, we often "backshift" the verb in the dependent clause to match the initial verb (same as *I **thought** you **were** dead!*). Just because you backshifted doesn't really imply anything about whether you might ***still*** need it, but Present Tense *in case I need to use it* strongly implies that although I haven't ***yet*** (at time of utterance) needed it, I still think I might do so in future. (If there's no possibility of me still needing it at time of utterance or later, only the backshifted version works).